# How to execute Orientdb server side function from Orientjs?

Tags: javascript, orientdb

I am using Orientjs to access a Orientdb database from a nodejs script, but the server side function does not effect the database.

**Server side script:**
This Javascript function `addTxt()` takes the argument `author` and `text`

```
var db = orient.getGraph();
db.command('sql','insert into Message (author, text) VALUES ("'+author+'", "'+text+'")');
return "1";
```

**Query:** This function has been tested in Orient Studio and the following query works:

```
SELECT addTxt("Testuser","foo")
```

**Nodejs/Orientjs:** When invoking this function from a nodejs script using Orientjs, it only returns

```
[ { '@type': 'd', addTxt: '1', '@rid': { cluster: -2, position: 1 } } ]
```

and the database remains untouched.

I have tried:

```
//some code

var OrientDB = require('orientjs');    
var server = OrientDB({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 2424,
});

var db = server.use({
    name: 'database',
    username: 'admin',
    password: 'pass'

db.query('SELECT addTxt(:arg1, :arg2)', {
    params: {arg1:"Testuser",arg2:"foo"}
}).then(function (response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

Other queries from Orientjs works.

What am I doing wrong? Is there an other way to invoke a server side function?

Comment: can you post the code of your function?

Comment: I added it to my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You explicit returns "1"

it is right that returns

```
[ { '@type': 'd', addTxt: '1', '@rid': { cluster: -2, position: 1 } } ]
```

try to directly explicit the commit in your function

db.commit()

Comment: Thanks! It is working with db.commit(). return "1" was just for debug purpose.

Comment: I ran into this same issue. There may be different levels that you need to commit if you are editing data with functions inside other functions. Too bad its not better documented.